# Determine build types and exclude resources in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am defining `productFlavors` in my `build.gradle` file (the one in the `app` directory). Each flavor has a corresponding `res/raw` directory with `.properties` files corresponding to the build type (debug, test, and release). Within my `main/res/raw` directory, I have  `build.properties`. Here's a visual of the directory structure:

- src

  - flavor1

    - res

      - raw

        - dev.properties
        - prod.properties
        - test.properties
  - flavor2

    - res

      - raw

        - dev.properties
        - ...
  - ...
  - main

    - res

      - raw

        - build.properties

I would like to copy the contents of `<flavor>/res/raw/<build_type>.properties` into `main/res/raw/build.properties` and only deploy `build.properties` into the APK.

How can I determine which build variant is being built from within `build.gradle` in order to copy the correct `<build_type>.properties` file?

How can I exclude the `<flavor>/res/raw` folder from being built into the APK?

Comment: I have found a solution and described it in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263567/how-to-exclude-res-folder-from-gradle-build-flavours/45581826#45581826

Answer (score 3):

You can have folders for a flavor + build type combination, which will let you do what you want without having to copy and rename files:

```
src
  flavor1
  flavor1Debug
    res
      raw
        build.properties
  flavor1Prod
    res
      raw
        build.properties
  flavor2
  flavor2Debug
    res
      raw
        build.properties
```

etc.

Comment: Ah, ok. I feel like I should have thought of that. :P In your example, are `flavor1Debug` and `flavor1Prod` nested underneath `flavor1`, or are they on the same directory level?

Comment: Your solution is not quite what I am wanting. After taking a look at my code again, I realize I DO want the three versions of the properties files available at compile time. For instance, I will sometimes need to access `prod.properties` and use those values while running a debug build. Because of that, I cannot simply hardcode the contents of `<flavor>/res/raw/<environment>.properties` into `<buildVariant>/res/raw/build.properties`. I would still like to know the answer to my question, not simply an alternative. Your solution is not wrong (so +1 for that), but it doesn't fit my requirements.

Comment: To answer your first question, though you maybe figured it out already, the `flavor1Debug` folder goes alongside the `flavor1` folder, not underneath it. To provide some insight into your second question, I think you have to think about it a different way -- don't think about "what variant is being built", but instead build a task that does the copying, and find the right variant-specific task to make it depend on. Sorry, I'm not trying to be intentionally vague, but it would take some research for me to figure out exactly how to do it. I believe there's API for getting the current variant.