# How to exclude files from main in my product flavor build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to exclude java files from src/main in my product flavor but the files are not getting excluded. I tried both ways by giving source code path and also package name. Can someone let me know how to exclude java files from main in my product flavor.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263567/how-to-exclude-res-folder-from-gradle-build-flavours/45581826#45581826

Comment: @Durga Malleswari, got any solution to this problem?