# Add folder to srcDir except for one file in gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing an android app with multiple flavors like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs += ["headend/ott/res"]
    }

    flavor1 {
        res.srcDirs += ["src/module1/res-splash"]
    }

    flavor2 {
        java.srcDirs += ["src/module1/java"]
        res.srcDirs += ["src/module1/res"]
        res.srcDirs += ["src/module2/res"]
        assets.srcDirs += ["src/module1/assets"]
    }

    test {
        res.srcDirs += ["src/test/resources"]
    }
    ...
```

My problem is that, in flavor2, some of the module2 resources are supposed to be replacements of ones already present in module1, but with my current approach it causes the build to fail with duplicate resources.

So what I need is a way to add "src/module1/res" to flavor2 but without including one specific file.

I've tried

```
res{
    srcDirs += ["src/module1/res"]
    res.srcDirs += ["src/module1/res"]        
    exclude 'src/module1/res/drawable/specific_file.xml'
}
```

But to no avail.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

After looking at multiple answers [like this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-exclude-certain-java-files-from-being-compiled/5287/4), the code that you have looks correct to me. However, [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36988285) stating that exclude paths are not implemented is still open.

This [alternate approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581826/984830) which references [these docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#keep-resources) may work for you instead. I suggest adding a resource directory inside your flavour2 directory/module and using it to include a discard file.

```
sourceSets {
    flavor2 {
        res {
            srcDirs += ["src/module1/res"]
            srcDirs += ["src/module2/res"]
        }
    }
 }
```

Then add `resources_discard.xml` to `module2/res/raw` with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
         tools:discard="@drawable/specific_file.xml" />
```

Comment: doesn't that discard the `module2/specific_file`? because what I need is to discard the `module1/specific_file` while adding a new `module2/specific_file`

Comment: Ah ok, so you are also including some files from module2 which are overrides? Can you update your question code to show what you have there then so I can see paths

Comment: I had that information already: "in flavor2, I need to replace some files in the res folder, which causes the build to fail with duplicate resources." Do you think it could be made clearer?

Comment: All of your code above includes only res from module1 ... no second source

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. In one of my projects, I was able to exclude java file from compiling by not using the `srcDir` path in the `exclude` path. `exclude` usually works without appending the `srcDir` path.

```
res{
    srcDirs += ["src/module1/res"]
    res.srcDirs += ["src/module1/res"]        
    exclude 'drawable/specific_file.xml'
}
```

Comment: As explained in my question, I've tried that already but it doesn't work

Comment: Focus on the `exclude` path. you have this `exclude 'src/module1/res/drawable/specific_file.xml'`, Can you try this `exclude 'drawable/specific_file.xml'`